# How to define a shaper in ejabberd for websocket connections?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'd like to define a shaper for connections using websocket.
These are configured via `ejabberd_http` listen module with the `ejabberd_http_ws` handler.

Is this possible?

Alternatively is it possible to define a global shaper no matter the transport?

I tried setting `shaper` option in the listen module, but it doesn't accept it.